# AWS Athena: How to run query on specific partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I expected that the "where" statement will reduce the query processing amount (3.71G)

```
SELECT  date_diff('day',current_timestamp,insert_time) 
FROM "accessagg"."access_agg" 
WHERE date_diff('day',current_timestamp,insert_time  ) <=2
```

My table contains an "Insert_time" column.
The table is not partitioned but from my knowledge, all the existing columns are partitioned by default and there is no option to create a partition by a specific column.
This table is not based on S3 bucket, I created this table using the Athena CREATE query

So how can I reduce the processing? or create a partition by this column.

[image]

Comment: partition and parquet are different things.  parquet is a columnar storage where a partition divides the data into different data sets by some criteria (like year over year) where as if the table had 10 columns, parquet would create a separate file for each column and store the actual unique data there.  The main table would just become indexes pointed to those columns which reduces data storage. for more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html  by defining a query that uses the partitioned value (year in my example), the engine only queries the relevant partitions.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to partition by?  date w/o time?  date with time? are you only looking at a years worth of data?  how can you subdivide the datasets to get what you're after? I'ts unlikely columnar (parquet) would help in this case unless you have tens of thousands of records with the exact same insert time. which columnar could reduce to 1.  The gretest benefit would be indexes; but I don't think Athena supports those.  Maybe you're after partition indexes? (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-athena-queries-aws-glue-data-catalog-partition-indexes/)

Comment: would need to see the DDL for your create table to know what could be done, but maybe  partition by year/month and then limit the data by year/month if current date is >= January 3rd, otherwise you'll need to pull data from 2 partitions.  Bear in mind if you have queries which don't look at data by date, then the overhead of creating these partitions could adversely effect their performance.   There's no silver bullet.  you're exchanging something for something.

Comment: I'm not sure what should I do. if I will change the insert_time column to be days_from_now (integer) the same query will be cheaper?

Comment: So the goal of the query is to return any users who have "accessed" the system in the past 2 days? without knowing how this data flows into your S3 bucket, I'd likely do one of two things: 1) create a bucket which just contains the past X days worth of access log data.  2) Create partitions on the data by month/year and then limit the query to current month/year unless it's the first 2 days of a month then pull in prior month/year if needed.  Option 1 is simplest but relies on data duplication for this need. But it's a simple job run.  Option 1 has zero risk to other queries. Option 2 has risk

Comment: A great read for understanding how to optimize usage of Amazon Athena: [Top 10 Performance Tuning Tips for Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/)

Comment: This table is not based on S3 bucket, I created this table using Athena CREATE query

Comment: where is access_agg data stored?  Athena isn't a database it's query engine.  Consider: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html

Comment: understand... so I need to set the partition when I create insert into statement

Comment: OK so how can I insert using INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... the date to specific partition

Comment: using an insert into the table and partitions are already created: The INSERT INTO statement supports writing a maximum of 100 partitions to the destination table.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html .  To create the table with partitions: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-create-use-partitioned-tables/.  So then when data is inserted depending on the partitions created, the data is assigned to the correct file.  Then when quering the data you limit by the partitions created thereby allowing the system to pick and use only certain files.